# How to point the action listener to a different file in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using netbeans for my Java swing application. I am trying to use mvc pattern. To do that, I have to set my Controller to be the action listener for many Gui components.

With netbeans, if I click on component to add an action  listener then it automatically generates the code (the listener). How can I use netbeans (through Gui designer) to point the action listener to another class/file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Left click on your component, go to Properties > Events and delete the event you created, accept. Then left click again and customize code, there you should be able to add you own action listener.

Comment: That will just let me add all code manually. I was to automate the process but just use my action listener in another class instead

Comment: Can you post the code. Also you could try to add a custom handler name in Properties > Events > ... > Add